# Intra-workspace dependencies in a Rust project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following crate layout taken from the [workspace RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1525-cargo-workspace.md):

```
Cargo.toml
src/
  lib.rs
dep1/
  Cargo.toml
  src/
    lib.rs
dep2/
  Cargo.toml
  src/
    lib.rs
```

I need `dep2` to import the `dep1` crate and the root crate.

1. What is the conventional way?
2. Is there a way to do it by referencing crates relative to the root, rather than relative to `dep2`?

Comment: Why do you need `dep2` to import the **root** crate? This suggests to me that either `dep2` should **be** the root crate (and the root crate should be a dependency), or they should be modules in the same crate, or there should be a third dependency `dep3` with both `dep2` and the root crate depending on `dep3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about how you declare the dependencies of "dep2"; it's the same as any other crate. You can easily test this by just trying it:

```
[dependencies.the_name_of_the_root_package]
path = "../"

[dependencies.dep1]
path = "../dep1"
```

No, there's no "from the root" option for the path. You don't move your crates around except once or twice in the lifetime of the project, so this shouldn't be a problem in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew that this way would work, but I didn't know if it was the idiomatic way to do it. For that, I had to ask.

I'm still new to the Rust ecosystem, but this build system seems to encourage creating a few large compilation units ('crates') rather than a lot of small ones (it should be one per source file unless technically necessary to make a larger compilation unit). I think large projects are going to get headaches when they see incremental build times.

Comment: @masonk I don't see what part of the build system encourages large compilation units; you can create as many crates as you'd like with differing amounts of code in them. If anything, workspaces would seem to nudge towards more crates with smaller per-crate sizes. Incremental compilation is being worked on (it's available but not enabled by default at the moment, IIRC).

Comment: I guess this is the wrong forum, but, in a nutshell, it is less work to add a source file to an existing compilation unit than it is to create a new compilation unit for each source file.

It looks like the long term plan is to offer incremental compilation at a level more granular than a crate. (https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/incremental-compilation-beta/4721). When that hits, I think it will squarely address my complaint. (But it hasn't yet).

Comment: Actually, I don't think incremental addresses all of my concerns: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/small-dependencies-in-rust-do-or-dont/14718/18?u=masonk